# Concurrent writes to DynamoDB using transaction api

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

We are using the dynamo DB transaction API.
In my application I am doing concurrent writes (unique items) to dynamo DB.
However i get the following exceptions

com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ResourceInUseException: Cannot create preexisting table (Service: null; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ResourceInUseException; Request ID: null)

Also can be do batch save when using dynamo DB transactions

Any inputs will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There's a big difference between concurrent createTable calls and put/write calls. You'll only get that error when you're calling createTable when it already exists.

You need to have strict control over how/when you create the table. Once your table is created, you should have no problems doing concurrent writes using any of the put/write APIs.

(Keep in mind you'll still get 4xx errors if you do conditional writes and the condition fails.)